# How can I know ahead of time whether I have to swipe my Octopus card when exiting a bus in Hong Kong?

Tags: tickets, budget, buses, hong-kong, fares

When taking the MTR in Hong Kong, one has to swipe one's Octopus card on the way in and out. How can I know ahead of time whether I have to swipe my Octopus card when exiting a bus in Hong Kong?

Comment: Great question. I was going to write "you don't", but apparently there are a handful of routes where you can swipe your octopus when getting out to qualify for a lower fare. [This 2018 document](https://gia.info.gov.hk/general/201803/21/P2018032100704_280406_1_1521626357868.pdf) from the Hong Kong government list the route numbers that supports so. I can't find an English nor a more updated version. Putting this as a comment as I don't have access to resources that can let me construct a good answer.

Comment: I found the english version: [link](https://www.lwb.gov.hk/eng/legco/LCQ19_21032018_6_annex_e.pdf), this is part of [the Government's response to a Legislative Council Member's question](https://www.lwb.gov.hk/eng/legco/21032018_6.htm) (Q2 and 3).

Comment: @B.Liu Thanks for the information, it seems to answer the question. By the way, [what does “ two-way section fare” mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/229498/3023)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [some bus routes on which have two-way section fares](https://www.lwb.gov.hk/eng/legco/21032018_6.htm), allowing you to qualify for a lower fare by swiping your card whilst getting off the bus:

> (2) and (3) At present, there are 38 bus routes with Octopus two-way section fares. Details of these routes are set out in the [Annex](https://www.lwb.gov.hk/eng/legco/21032018_6.htm). In 2017, the average daily passenger trips made on buses under the Scheme was 544 000. In 2017-18 revised estimate, the Government's reimbursement of the revenue forgone to the operators under the Scheme is $1.1 billion. Currently, bus companies do not have information regarding the data of passenger trips enjoying two-way section fares.

The complete list of these bus routes can be found in [this PDF file](https://www.lwb.gov.hk/eng/legco/LCQ19_21032018_6_annex_e.pdf) (updated in 2018).